# Convert DRS to Sentence

Tags: prolog, attempto

How do you convert Discourse-Repsentation-Structure (DRS) to text Sentence?
Here are some DRS samples:

```
drs([A, B], [object(A, book, countable, na, eq, 1)-1/4, predicate(B, own, named('Peter'), A)-1/2]).
drs([], [question(drs([A, B], [query(A, what)-1/1, predicate(B, own, named('Peter'), A)-1/4]))]).
drs([], [question(drs([A, B], [object(A, book, countable, na, eq, 1)-1/5, predicate(B, own, named('Peter'), A)-1/3]))]).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

To have ACE text: `drs_to_ace(Drs, AceSentenceList)` will paraphrase the Drs.

To plain text: `drs_to_ascii(Drs, DrsAscii)`
They are imported from:

```
:- use_module(utils/drs_to_ace, [drs_to_ace/2]).
:- use_module(utils/drs_to_ascii).
```

Hint: `runape.pl` contains lots of useful hacks into APE. To do my own processing, I first remove the annotations Pred-NumLine/NumToken to Pred.

Comment: Is [tag:ape] really an appropriate tag?

Comment: @false: you are right, should use Attempto, but this tag doesn't yet exist.

Comment: Or [tag:attempto-controlled-english]?

Comment: You can create tags on the fly, just write it. Tag info can follow later by anybody from  the community.

Comment: i have to do this to use it..  [/home/xxxxx/.local/share/swi-prolog/pack/APE/prolog/utils/drs_to_ace.pl']., how to fix that ?

Comment: for use_module(library(ape)) i have to do this first : ?- assert(user:file_search_path(pack, '/home/xxxxx/.local/share/swi-prolog/pack/APE/prolog/')).

Comment: @sten yes you have to "include" library file drs_to_ace.pl if you want to call drs_to_ace/2. Its ok to leave out this file, if you use **only** drs_to_ascii/2. This is the module system in SWI-Prolog. Maybe I didn't understand your comment, post a new question ?